# wp_list_comments() not working

Tags: wordpress

I've created a custom theme from scratch, nothing fancy, simple theme. I'm currently using Wordpress 3.2.1. I put wp_list_comments() in the comments.php to list the comments, and it doesn't work at all! No comments displayed. Tried putting it in single.php, tried also deactivating all the plugins - still nothing. I used the default function, just wp_list_comments(); with no arguments. Could anybody suggest why it might be not working?

Comment: It would help to see the code in your comments.php.

Comment: My code in comments.php:

`<?php comment_form(array('title_reply'=>'Leave a Comment', 'comment_notes_before'=>'', 'comment_notes_after'=>'')); ?>
<?php wp_list_comments(); ?>`

And then I included that comments.php into my single.php
The first part of the code (Leave a Comment form) shows, the list of existing comments does not.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Did you try `<?php comments_template(); ?>` in single.php?  You seem to imply in your comment above that you were doing something like `<?php include('comments.php')?>`  This won't work, because the comments haven't been queried from the database--`comments_template()` does that, then includes `comments.php` in your theme root.

Does that help?

Comment: Did not know it took a special call, but makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. Nothing like a function you have to call client side to query for data that includes your markup... ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.
I added

```
<?php include('comments.php')?>
```

and comments started to appear.

Answer (score 0):

My resolution was to load the comments and include them as the argument in the wp_list_comments() function call. In this case, it's to include Woocommerce comments and their associated formatting.

```
<?php
$comments = get_comments( array('post_id' => get_the_id()) );
?>
<ol class="commentlist">
    <?php wp_list_comments( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_review_list_args', array( 'callback' => 'woocommerce_comments' ) ), $comments ); ?>
</ol>
```