# Where to apply wp_list_comments in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm looking for a website or some help for wp_list_comments and where you put them on a WordPress page. I also understand that you need to put the necessary code on the functions.php page as well. But how to get the comments listed on a post is getting me stumped. Any help will do.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question (somewhat), I took a look at this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052297/wp-list-comments-not-working?rq=1) link. I also read about the comments.php file that WordPress has and I Googled it. Found some [great examples here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/partial-and-miscellaneous-template-files/comments/).